# Bijective mapping from integers to a variable number of bits

Tags: code-golf, integer, open-ended-function, bitwise

A variable number of bits is an array of 0 or more bits. So `[0, 1]` is a variable number of bits, but so is `[]`.

Write a function or program that, given an nonnegative integer returns a variable number of bits such that every integer has a one-to-one (bijective) mapping with an array.

There are an infinite amount of such mappings, you are free to construct one as you please, but it **must** be one-to-one. Your mapping must *conceptually* be one-to-one for an arbitrarily sized integer, but it's OK if your *implementation* fails for large integers due to numerical limits of types in your preferred language (e.g. C's `int`).

As an example of what is **not** a one-to-one mapping, is simply listing the binary digits of the integer. In such a system 5 becomes `[1, 0, 1]` (or `0b101`), but it's not one-to-one, because `0b0101` or `[0, 1, 0, 1]` also means 5.

It should be fairly obvious that a mapping is not one-to-one if it skips an integer (e.g. it doesn't work for 5), but I'd like to make it clear that skipping a variable bit array is also not one-to-one. You must map to every possible variable bit array, including `[]`.

---

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: May we return a string of 0's and 1's?

Comment: @xnor Yes, a string of 0s and 1s is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Jelly, 3 bytes

```
‘BḊ
```

Same idea as xnor: maps `0 1 2 3 4 ...` to `[] [0] [1] [0 0] [0 1] ...`; the code is basically `increment → binary → remove first`.

[Try it out online](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCYQuG4igooVGhpcyBydW5zIHRoZSBhYm92ZSBhcyBhIGZ1bmN0aW9uIG9uIGFsbCBpbnB1dHM6KQrDkeKCrA&input=&args=MCwxLDIsMyw0LDUsNiw3).

Answer (score 10):

### Python, 20 bytes

```python
lambda n:bin(~n)[4:]
```

Test:

```python
>> [bin(~n)[4:] for n in range(16)]
['', '0', '1', '00', '01', '10', '11', '000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111', '0000']
```

Doing `lambda n:bin(n+1)[3:]` increments the input, then takes the binary representation with the first symbol removed (`[3:]` because the prefix `0b` is two chars chars). Since any positive number starts with 1 in binary, this uniquely gives a binary representation.

A byte is saved by instead using the bit complement `~n` to get the negation `-(n+1)`, and removing the negative sign by chopping off one more symbol.

Comment: Inverse: `lambda s:int('1'+s,2)-1`.

Answer (score 2):

### Pyth, 5 bytes

```
t.BhQ
```

Simply a translation of [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71925/3808) into Pyth.

`Q` is eval()'d input(), `h` increments it, `.B` converts it to a binary string, and `t` takes the "tail" (which is everything except the first character).

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, <s>41</s> <s>38</s> <s>30</s> 29 bytes

```
l="":[b:x|x<-l,b<-"01"]
(l!!)
```

Usage example: `(l!!) 4` -> `"10"`.

Starting with the empty list as the first element, walk lazily through the list and append the current element with `0` and with `1` in front of it.

Edit: @xnor saved <s>3</s> 11 bytes. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting idea. The iterated function can be written `[(0:),(1:)]<*>`

Comment: @xnor: Oh, you showed me the `<*>` trick before, but I forgot about it. Thanks again!

Comment: Ooh, you can define the whole list lazily: `l=[]:[b:x|x<-l,b<-[0,1]];(l!!)`.

Comment: @xnor: Great! Thanks a lot! Oh, switching to strings saves one more byte.

Comment: I feel like there should be some shorter way to express `[b:x|x<-l,b<-"01"]` with a product or concat-map, but the product expression `(:)<$>[0,1]<*>l` goes in the wrong order, first prepending 0 to everything, never getting to 1 because the list is infinite. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @xnor: this is a far as I can get: `l="":(flip(:)<$>l<*>"01")`. 2 bytes longer.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 29 bytes

```
x=>(~x).toString(2).slice(2)
```

Same idea as xnor.

```js
f=x=>(~x).toString(2).slice(2);
[...Array(100)].map((v,x)=>A.textContent+=x + ': ' + f(x) + '\n')
```

```html
<pre id=A></pre>
```

Comment: This is readily extended to other bases as per http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/78990

Answer (score 1):

## Jolf, 4 bytes

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=d0Joag)

```
wBhj
  hj  input + 1
 B    converted to binary
w     with first removed.
```

Very simple strategy, also happens to be the shortest.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 35 bytes

```haskell
h 1=[]
h n=mod n 2:h(div n 2)
h.(+1)
```

Haskell doesn't have a binary built-in, so the (reversed) conversion is done manually. To remove the initial 1, the base case has `1` transform to the empty list.

Edit: Saved a byte by conjugating by the `+1` instead.

```haskell
h 0=[]
h m=1-mod m 2:h(div(m+1)2-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 40 bytes

```
f(n){if(++n/2)putchar(n%2+48),f(n/2-1);}
```

Converts the input to bijective base 2 (with symbols `0` and `1`), like the other answers.

[ideone it!](http://ideone.com/ocbmMs)