# Bijective mapping from integers to a variable number of trits

Tags: code-golf, integer

### This challenge is a harder version of [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71924/bijective-mapping-from-integers-to-a-variable-number-of-bits).

A variable number of trits is an array of 0 or more trits (a trit is a [ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_numeral_system) digit). So `[0, 2, 2, 1]` is a variable number of trits, but so is `[]`.

Write a function or program that, given an non-negative integer returns a variable number of trits such that every integer has a one-to-one (bijective) mapping with an array.

There are an infinite amount of such mappings, you are free to construct one as you please, but it **must** be one-to-one. Your mapping must *conceptually* be one-to-one for an arbitrarily sized integer, but it's OK if your *implementation* fails for large integers due to numerical limits of types in your preferred language (e.g. C's `int`).

As an example of what is **not** a one-to-one mapping, is simply listing the ternary digits of the integer. In such a system 5 becomes `[1, 2]` (because `1*3^1 + 2*3^0 = 5`), but it's not one-to-one, because `[0, 1, 2]` also means 5 (because `0*3^2 + 1*3^1 + 2*3^0 = 5`).

It should be fairly obvious that a mapping is not one-to-one if it skips an integer (e.g. it doesn't work for 5), but I'd like to make it clear that skipping a variable trit array is also not one-to-one. You must map to every possible variable trit array, including `[]`.

#### Bonus challenge

You will be awarded the official Super Smaht® Award™ if your answer includes an algorithm (not necessarily in your golfed program) that not only works for base 2 or 3, but for all bases.

---

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: input/output format?

Comment: @KennyLau The standard stuff, you can write a program or function, taking a list  of trits, or a string containing the trits (e.g. [1, 0, 2] or "102" or "1, 0, 2") and you must output a single integer to stdout, function return, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
tjyhQ3
```

Explanation:

```
    Q    Input number.
   h     Add 1.
  y      Multiply by 2.
 j   3   Convert to base 3 as a list.
t        Remove the first element.
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=tjyhQ3&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A11%0A12%0A13%0A14%0A15%0A16%0A17%0A18%0A19)

### Inverse function: Pyth, 14 bytes

```
t/i+-2%sQ2Q3 2
```

Explanation:

```
        Q        Input list.
       s         Sum.
      %  2       Modulo 2.
    -2           Subtract from 2.
   +      Q      Prepend to input list.
  i        3     Convert from base 3.
 /           2   Divide by 2.
t                Subtract 1.
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=t/i%2B-2%25sQ2Q3%202&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=[]%0A[1]%0A[0]%0A[2]%0A[0,%201]%0A[1,%200]%0A[1,%202]%0A[2,%201]%0A[0,%200]%0A[0,%202]%0A[1,%201]%0A[2,%200]%0A[2,%202]%0A[0,%200,%201]%0A[0,%201,%200]%0A[0,%201,%202]%0A[0,%202,%201]%0A[1,%200,%200]%0A[1,%200,%202]%0A[1,%201,%201])

The bijection looks like this:

```
0: []
1: [1]
2: [0]
3: [2]
4: [0, 1]
5: [1, 0]
6: [1, 2]
7: [2, 1]
8: [0, 0]
9: [0, 2]
10: [1, 1]
11: [2, 0]
12: [2, 2]
13: [0, 0, 1]
14: [0, 1, 0]
15: [0, 1, 2]
16: [0, 2, 1]
17: [1, 0, 0]
18: [1, 0, 2]
19: [1, 1, 1]
⋮
```

## General base

To make this work in any base b, simply replace `3` with b, `2` with (b − 1), and `y` with `*`(b − 1).

Comment: No way... how come the algorithm is so simple...

Comment: Also, it would be interesting if you show the inverse function.

Comment: @orlp Added the inverse function!

Comment: I think I can prove that this algorithm generalizes to all bases.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 24 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n?f(--n/3|0)+n%3:''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEtLshMSS3Kzc/LTq38/z/NNs/WLs8@TUNXN0/fuMZAUztP1dhKXf1/Wn6Rgkamgq2CgbVCpoKirYKRqRmQpa2tqZCcn1ecn5Oql5OfDlShraD@qG2SOpBO08jU1LT@DwA)

Implements [the standard ternary bijective numeration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration#Definition), except with the digits reduced by 1.

How it works: First, check if `n` is 0, returning the empty string if so. Otherwise, `n` is pre-decremented, and that value is divided by 3 and rounded down (`|0` is a short way to do the rounding) and passed recursively to `f` – the final digit will contribute 1, 2, or 3, while the rest contribute a multiple of 3, so \$\lfloor\frac{n-1}{3}\rfloor\$ is the value the non-final digits should represent on their own. Finally, `n%3` appends the final digit, reduced by 1 from the standard (`n` having already been decremented).

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ḃ3’
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjmbjRw0zgfS2w@2PmtYcnfRw5wwgHfn/v7ERAA)

```
ḃ3   Convert to bijective base 3
  ’  Decrement all digits
```

### Inverse, 3 bytes

```
‘ḅ3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY@xDYAwDAT7TMEAKWwzTpSSBmUBOoSEWIEhGICeScgiRgmW3o2tnE6f9zyVsqjW9XzvfdTnqNulmkLKMSRqg9uQ/owD2WbbnbNxNs7GxbgYF@MtB1EujSCw@wsCQxAI4vq4SmhFKOY6@9oQGIJAEHeau@4X8gc)

```
‘    Increment all digits
 ḅ3  Convert from base 3
```

Both versions can be made to use an arbitrary base by removing the `3`.

Answer (score 0):

## Jelly, 12 bytes

```
ḤR‘b3Ḣ’$Ðḟị@
```

There is no empty list in Jelly; it is represented as `0` (an integer not a list).

For other bases: change `Ḥ` to `×n` and `b3` to `bn`, where `n` is the intended base.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bikUuKAmGIz4bii4oCZJMOQ4bif4buLQA&input=&args=Mjc)

[Test suite.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bikUuKAmGIz4bii4oCZJMOQ4bif4buLQArDh-KCrA&input=&args=MCwxLDIsMyw0LDUsNiw3LDgsOSwxMCwxMSwxMiwxMywxNCwxNSwxNiwxNywxOCwxOSwyMCwyMSwyMiwyMywyNCwyNSwyNiwyNw)

## For other bases

It only costs **11 bytes** if given base as second input.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w5dS4oCYYuG4ouKAmSTDkOG4n-KBuOG7iw&input=&args=Mjc+NA)

[Test suite.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w5dS4oCYYuG4ouKAmSTDkOG4n-KBuOG7iwrDp-KCrA&input=&args=MCwxLDIsMyw0LDUsNiw3LDgsOSwxMCwxMSwxMiwxMywxNCwxNSwxNiwxNywxOCwxOSwyMCwyMSwyMiwyMywyNCwyNSwyNiwyNw+NA)

## Algorithm

I thought of appending a `1` before the list and then convert it to a ternary.

That way, `[0,0]` will become `100 = 9` while `[0,0,0]` will become `1000 = 27`.

However, a problem arises: that `2011` and `1011` both map to `[0,1,1]`.

I only need [numbers whose ternary representation starts with `1`](http://oeis.org/A132141).

Therefore, I generated those whose ternary representation starts with `1`, and then use their **index** instead.

That is, the list begins as `[1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, ...]`.

Therefore:

- `1` will be mapped to `1`
- `2` will be mapped to `3`
- `3` will be mapped to `4`
- `4` will be mapped to `5`
- `5` will be mapped to `9`
- `n` will be mapped to `a(n)` where `a` is that list.

There's another problem: both `0` and `1` are mapped to the empty list. Therefore, I removed `1` from the list, making `a = [3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, ...]`.

Those are the integers whose ternary representation starts with `1`, **except `1`**.

The same algorithm can be applied to other bases.

Answer (score 0):

## Jelly, 6 bytes

```
‘Ḥb3ṫ2
```

Translation of [Kaseorg's answer in Pyth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78998/48934).

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCY4bikYjPhuasy&input=&args=Mjc)

Hardcoded base: [try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCYw5czYjThuasy&input=&args=Mjc)

Given base: [try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCYw5figbTigJnCpGLhuasy&input=&args=Mjc+NA)

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 9 bytes

```
ri)_+3b(;
```

Translation of [Kaseorg's answer in Pyth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78998/53386).

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cmkpXyszYig7&input=MTk)

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 31 bytes

```
n=>(n*2+2).toString(3).slice(1)
```

Since everyone else is translating @AndreasKaseorg's fine answer. Generic version (36 bytes):

```
b=>n=>(-~n*~-b).toString(b).slice(1)
```